# Separate Array based on Gaps in linear key

Tags: java, arrays

I am looking to separate a single array into separate arrays based on gaps in the key. For example take this scenario:

> I'm attempting to create separate datasets (arrays) for consecutive days of the month. If a day is missed a new dataset needs to be created starting with the next day that has a value.

The data is retrieved in one array like so:

```
[1:10, 2:8, 4:5, 5:12, 8:6, 9:10, 10:5, 11:4, 13:6, 14:5]
```

I would like to output:

```
[1:10, 2:8], [4:5, 5:12], [8:6, 9:10, 10:5, 11:4], [13:6, 14:5]
```

How would I achieve this?

I currently have this:

```
ArrayList<Entry> allValues = new ArrayList<>();

// Data Retrieval from the Server is Here (hidden for privacy)
// Each data entry contains key and value
// This is converted into a data model "Entry" which is essentially an x & y coordinate ( Entry(x,y) )
// and then added to the allValues List

List<ArrayList<Entry>> rawDataSets = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Entry> tempDataSet = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < allValues.size(); i++){
    Entry tempEntry = allValues.get(i);
    if(i == tempEntry.getX()){
        tempDataSet.add(tempEntry);
    }else{
        if(tempDataSet.size() > 0) {
            rawDataSets.add(tempDataSet);
            tempDataSet.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi David, can you share us what you've tried so far ?

Comment: Indeed. The whole question hinges on that

Comment: @Tom I have added my first attempt

Comment: Not sure about the rest of the algo yet, but `tempDataSet.clear();` is definitely not going to work.  You'll end up with a result full of copies of the very last temp data set.  You want to start with a fresh new set every time: `tempDataSet = new ArrayList<>();`'

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do trick:

```
ArrayList<Entry> allValues = new ArrayList<>();

// Assuming at this point that `allValues` is sorted in ascending order by X values.
// If necessary, it can be sorted with 
//
//    Collections.sort(allValues, Comparator.comparing(Entry::getX));
//
List<ArrayList<Entry>> rawDataSets = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Entry> tempDataSet = new ArrayList<>();

for (Entry tempEntry : allValues){
    if (!tempDataSet.isEmpty() &&
        tempEntry.getX() != tempDataSet.get(tempDataSet.size()-1).getX() + 1)
    {
        // tempDataSet is not empty, and tempEntry's X is not 
        // consecutive with the X of tempDataSet's last entry, so it's
        // it's time finish with the current tempDataSet and start fresh
        // with a new one.  
        rawDataSets.add(tempDataSet);
        tempDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    // Regardless of what happened, or didn't happen, with tempDataSet above, 
    // the current allValues entry now belongs with the current tempDataSet
    tempDataSet.add(tempEntry);
}
// Now add any final non-empty tempDataSet (there will always be one if
// allValues wasn't empty) onto rawDataSets
if (!tempDataSet.isEmpty()) {
    rawDataSets.add(tempDataSet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a number of attempts I think I found the solution, although I'm not sure if this is the most effective:

```
List<ArrayList<Entry>> rawDataSets = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Entry> tempDataSet = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i <= allValues.get(allValues.size() - 1).getX(); i++){
    int matchedIndex = -1;
    for(int j = 0; j < allValues.size(); j++){
        if(allValues.get(j).getX() == i){
            matchedIndex = j;
        }
    }

    if(matchedIndex != -1) {
        Entry tempEntry = allValues.get(matchedIndex);
        tempDataSet.add(tempEntry);
    } else {
        if (tempDataSet.size() > 0) {
            rawDataSets.add(tempDataSet);
            tempDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
}
```